# How to upload canvas image to storage on Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, canvas

I have small laravel project that need to upload file from canvas to storage/uploads/imgs. This is my canvas

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

I may need ajax for client as below

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('image');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/route-here",
    data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL
    }
}).done(function(o) {
    console.log('saved'); 
});
```

But I'm not sure for coding in server(Laravel) side. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: `id='image'` or `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');`. Change one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont use Canvas, but do a bit of file uploading... You can use standard php methods for moving files in Laravel... Also, whilst you can definitely use AJAX, you could also accomplish this via a form...

Example of how I handle the upload in my controller:

```
if ($request->file('image')) {

    $asset = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

        $request->file('image')->move(
               base_path() . '/storage/app/uploads/imgs/', $asset
        );

}
```

I would also normally, do a check for path (as if your path doesn't exist - it will fail), duplicate file name etc before the ->move method is invoked.

A better way long term is to learn how the Laravel Storage class works - which is less code - but needs "disks" configured correctly as well as including the class in your controller etc.

Hope above helps point you in right direction...

Comment: Thanks, I solved already. This is my code $newname = time().'.'.explode('/',explode(':',substr($base64,0,strpos($base64,';')))[1])[1];
        Image::make($request->img)->save(public_path('storage/uploads/treatment/').$newname);

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution can you please explain where it  '$base64' will come from.